# Azure ML - Import Hive Query Failing - Hive over ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-machine-learning-service

We are working on Azure ML and ADLS combination. Since HDInsight Cluster is working over ADLS, we are trying to use Hive Query and HDFS route and running into problems. 
Request your help in solving the problem of reading data from hive query and writing to HDFS. Below is the error URL for reference:

https://studioapi.azureml.net/api/sharedaccess?workspaceId=025ba20578874d7086e6c495cc49a3f2&signature=ZMUCNMwRjlrksrrmsrx5SaGedSgwMmO%2FfSHvq190%2F1I%3D&sharedAccessUri=https%3A%2F%2Fesprodussouth001.blob.core.windows.net%2Fexperimentoutput%2Fccf9a206-730d-4773-b44e-a2dd8c6e87b9%2Fccf9a206-730d-4773-b44e-a2dd8c6e87b9.txt%3Fsv%3D2015-02-21%26sr%3Db%26sig%3DHkuFm8B2Ba1kEWWIwanqlv%2FcQPWVz0XYveSsZnEa0Wg%3D%26st%3D2017-10-16T18%3A31%3A06Z%26se%3D2017-10-17T18%3A36%3A06Z%26sp%3Dr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Machine Learning supports Hive but not over ADLS.